details about VK_PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR_KHR
I've read the description about this present mode. However, I still have some questions.
The description of this mode says that the internal queue is a single-entry queue, which means that new present requests are put into the queue through this single-entry and presentation engine fetch requests also from this single-entry. And if the queue is full, new request will replace the old ones in the queue.
Is the replacement here that removing all the old ones in the queue and place the new one into the queue? As if it is not so, that it only replaces the top one at the entry with the new request, then requests fetched from the queue after this new one being taken and executed will present old images associate with them.
